# PicklingError in when using KerasClassifier for Cross-Validation in Spark

Tags: keras, pyspark

Though I am able to run the following code perfectly on my local:

```
`from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
 from keras.models import Sequential
 from keras.layers import Dense
 def build_classifier():
     classifier = Sequential()
     classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
     classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
     classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
     classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
     return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)`
```

I am getting `PicklingError` : `Can't pickle <function build_classifier at 0x7f98f3cbabf8>: attribute lookup build_classifier on __main__ failed`

Based on my understanding of the `PicklingError` when trying to parallelize in `Python`, it looks like there is some issue with the position where I have defined the function, but I am not able to make it run. How can I troubleshoot this?